# JavaFX CSS Lines Won't Intersect

Tags: java, css, javafx

When I'm creating the interior border for my Sudoku grid, a part of it does not show up whenever it hits an intersecting point. However, in my Java code, if I remove either of the double 'for' loops for 'topBorder' or 'rightBorder', the border goes entirely across the grid. But if the double 'for' loops are there, a portion of the border is missing.

CSS Code:

```
.topBorder {
-fx-border-color: black;
-fx-pref-width: 3em; 
-fx-pref-height: 3em; 
-fx-border-width: 3 0 0 0;
}

.rightBorder {
-fx-border-color: black;
-fx-pref-width: 3em; 
-fx-pref-height: 3em; 
-fx-border-width: 0 3 0 0;
}
```

Sample Java code:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
                if((tf2D[col][row] == tf2D[i][3]) ||
                        (tf2D[col][row] == tf2D[i][6])) {
                    limitNumberTextField.getStyleClass().add("topBorder");
                }
            }

for(int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
                if((tf2D[col][row] == tf2D[2][j]) ||
                        (tf2D[col][row] == tf2D[5][j])) {
                    limitNumberTextField.getStyleClass().add(
                            "rightBorder");
                }
            }
```

Image:

[Missing border at intersection points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bt5Ib.jpg)

Comment: What's wrong with the approach I suggested in [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34218434/sudoku-gui-grid-lines)?

Comment: Nothing at all, I was just having some issues getting used to the pseudo classes. I've never had any experience with them before. However, I really appreciate your help, James_D. Thanks a bunch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If an element has both the style class `topBorder` and the style class `rightBorder`, you try to apply both border styles (which contradict each other). When this happens, the last rule appearing in the style sheet is applied, i.e. you get the rule

```
-fx-border-color: black;
-fx-pref-width: 3em; 
-fx-pref-height: 3em; 
-fx-border-width: 0 3 0 0;
```

This explicitly provides no top border, so there's no border on the top for cells with both style classes.

You could try adding a specific rule for cells with both style classes:

```
.topBorder {
-fx-border-color: black;
-fx-pref-width: 3em; 
-fx-pref-height: 3em; 
-fx-border-width: 3 0 0 0;
}

.rightBorder {
-fx-border-color: black;
-fx-pref-width: 3em; 
-fx-pref-height: 3em; 
-fx-border-width: 0 3 0 0;
}

.topBorder.rightBorder {
-fx-border-color: black;
-fx-pref-width: 3em; 
-fx-pref-height: 3em; 
-fx-border-width: 3 3 0 0;
}
```