# JavaFX pannable GridPane

Tags: java, javafx, pan, gridpane

For my current project, I need a large even grid with a transparent background that one can zoom and pan across.  I initially tried to use a `ScrollPane` with its `setPannable(true)`, but soon discovered that a scrollpane background will remain opague even when you call `setStyle("-fx-background-color: transparent")` or `setStyle("-fx-background: transparent")`.  So with that easy option eliminated, I need to make the GridPane in question directly pannable.

I've tried several things already, including trying to bind the mouse position to the `GridPane`'s Translate property(which quite simply didn't work), and I failed to get the more promising alternative to work properly:

```
    GridPane gridView = new GridPane();
    int x;
    int y;
    gridView.setOnDragEntered( (event) -> {
        x = event.getX();
        y = event.getY();
    });
    gridView.setOnDragDetected( (event) -> {
        gridView.setTranslateX(X - event.getX());
        gridView.setTranslateY(Y - event.getY());
    });
```

However, this only makes the map jump up and to the left, rather than to make it slowly pan with the mouse as intended.

Comment: Could you possibly use draw lines on a Canvas instead of having a grid pane?

Comment: I don't think so, because each square on the grid needs to contain a node which triggers an event depending on its location and the data being represented within that square.

Comment: Check this out and see if it's something you might be able to use. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33534594/generating-an-n-x-n-grid/33535310#33535310. It's in Swing, but you can transfer it to FX. Also, Spanning and Zooming can be another property that changes x and y position. If this solution is acceptable, I'll help you code Zooming and panning.

Comment: Can you place the GridPane within a StackPane within the ScrollPane, with the content that needs to appear under the grid lower down on the StackPane?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to mostly figure it out.  The one remaining problem is that the `GridPane` is rather jittery when it is panned, but it's at an acceptable level for now.

```
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    gridView.setOnMouseDragged((event) -> {
        if(x != 0){ //prevent from panning before values are initialized
            gridView.setTranslateX( gridView.getTranslateX() + limit(event.getX() - x, 25));
            gridView.setTranslateY( gridView.getTranslateY() + limit(event.getY() - y, 25));
        }
        x = (int)event.getX();
        y = (int)event.getY();
    });
```

Where the `Limit(double num, double limit)` method limits the input num to the range [-limit, limit].  Reducing the limit decreases the jitter, but it does so at the expense of decreasing responsiveness as well.